# Find strong reference in instruments only for loops

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

I have a question for apples example for memory handling in swift here:
[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

In the first example there is no weak variable in both classes with strong reference to members. --> so i got a loop here. 
In Instruments it is no problem to find a loop. But how can i find strong references like in the second example like that:

```
   class Person {
        let name: String
        init(name: String) { self.name = name }
        var apartment: Apartment?
        deinit { print("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
    }

    class Apartment {
        let unit: String
        init(unit: String) { self.unit = unit }
        weak var tenant: Person?
        deinit { print("Apartment \(unit) is being deinitialized") }
    }
```

called like that:

```
var john: Person?
var unit4A: Apartment?

john = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
unit4A = Apartment(unit: "4A")

john!.apartment = unit4A
unit4A!.tenant = john
```

in Instruments there are no loops to find. How can i find that apartment is strong to Person?